# ngOnChange dont detect change when i set value in Input

Tags: angular, angular-input

I have an @Input that does something when it's true ngOnChange doesn't detect when it's false

```
@Input() viewMode: boolean;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.viewMode.currentValue !== undefined) {    
      if (changes.viewMode.currentValue ) {
        this.populateForm(this._event);
      }else{
        this.doSomething()
      }
    }
  }


setValue(){

   this.viewMode = false; 
}
```

When I call the setValue function it doesn't fall into ngOnChange

Comment: is there any error in console? Print the value inside the `if.. else` condition.Make sure that you have in parent has something like `<app-child [viewMode]="myVal?true:false"></app-child>`

Comment: Can't you call this.poupulateForm inside setValue method?

Comment: @Chellappan no i have editableMode and viewMode i change state ever value change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this doubt myself also few days back. And what I found out is - `ngOnChanges` does not fire this way. ngOnChanges only runs when input of component changes from outside. i.e. Suppose you have,

```js
<app-selector [editMode]="true"></app-selector>
```

And this changes to,

```js
<app-selector [editMode]="false"></app-selector>
```

Now only angular will run ngOnchanges. If you want to do something whenever the property of this variable changes, you should use the setter and getter for this variable like so,

```js
private _viewMode: boolean;

@Input() set viewMode(mode) {
  this._viewMode = mode;
  this.populateForm(this._event);
}

get viewMode() {
  return this._viewMode;
}
```

Now you can call your function like `this.setValue()` and your form will populate everytime.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` only runs when the Input change comes from a template binding like `<component [someInput]="value">`. If you set it manually like this `component.someInput = value`, that happens outside the change detection cycle and you need to let Angular know somehow that you’ve changed something.

if you still want the `ngOnChanges` to be triggered, you will have to do it manually. i.e.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

setValue(){
  this.viewMode = false; 
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Hope it helps and clarifies your doubt!

Comment: dont detect the changes :/